# Create an array using longest length of arrays passed to a function, using Math.max?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I am trying to build a new array with a length that is equal to the longest array that is passed to a function. There can be an infinite number of arrays passed to the function, which is why I am trying to use `Math.max`.

I worked this up that uses loops...:

```js
function sumInternalValues() {
  let arrays = Array.from(arguments);
  let longest = 0;

  arrays.forEach(arr => {
    longest = (arr.length > longest) ? arr.length : longest;
  })

  let newArr = new Array(longest);
  //... do other things but for sake of this question, return here now
  return newArr.length;
}

let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let arr2 = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

console.log(sumInternalValues(arr1, arr2));
```

But **how can I get Math.max to work** with this instead?

```
function sumInternalValues() {
    let newArr = new Array(Math.max.apply(Math, arguments.length?));
}
```

---

*Note: I will be answering my own question based on the [guidelines here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). I spent a fair amount of time trying to get this and didn't find much support on SO.*

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by capturing the arguments as an array using [`array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), and then mapping the resulting array to get just lengths. And then `apply` that array to the `Math.max` function:

```js
function sumInternalValues() {
  let args = Array.from(arguments);
  let newArr = new Array(Math.max.apply(Math, args.map(a => a.length)));
  // ... do some other things, but for the sake of this question, return here
  return newArr.length
}

let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let arr2 = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

console.log(sumInternalValues(arr1, arr2));
```

Answer (score 0):

A dense array:

```
let denseArr = Object.assign([], arr1, arr2).fill(undefined);
```

A sparse array:

```
let sparseArr = [];
sparseArr.length = Math.max(...[arr1, arr2].map(arr => arr.length));
```